# botão iniciar / pausar

Tags: c#

Eu tenho um código que faz um cronômetro. Atualmente tenho 1 botão para começar o tempo e outro para continuar o tempo após ter parado. Se clicar no iniciar ele começa de novo.

como posso ter apenas 1 botão para iniciar e pausar?

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private int totalSeconds;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
            {
                this.comboBox1.Items.Add(i.ToString());
                this.comboBox2.Items.Add(i.ToString());

            }
            this.comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 30;
            this.comboBox2.SelectedIndex = 59;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int minutes = int.Parse(this.comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
            int seconds = int.Parse(this.comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString());
            totalSeconds = (minutes * 60) + seconds;
            this.timer1.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.timer1.Stop();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (totalSeconds > 0)
            {
                totalSeconds--;
                int minutes = totalSeconds / 60;
                int seconds = totalSeconds - (minutes * 60);
                this.label3.Text = minutes.ToString() + ":" + seconds.ToString();

            }
            else
            {
                this.timer1.Stop();
                MessageBox.Show("Tempo Acabou!");
            }

        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            totalSeconds = totalSeconds + 60;
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.timer1.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: alguem por favor?

Comment: para que tanta pressa em corrigir em bloquear os posts e nao ha ninguem que ajuda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não indico usar o `Timer` para essa operação, visto que o `Timer` é um repetidor de eventos após um determinado período, e não um cronometro. Mas o .NET tem uma classe de cronometro, chamada [`System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netframework-4.8), mas ela não tem a mesma função de um `Timer`, assim como vice-versa.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
...
public Stopwatch contador = new Stopwatch();
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (contador.IsRunning) {
        contador.Stop();
    } else {
        contador.Start();
    }
}
```

O método `Start` inicia ou retoma a medição do tempo decorrido de um intervalo. Se quiser começar de novo a medição de tempo, use o método `Restart`.

- O `Restart` irá zerar o contador e irá imediatamente começar uma nova contagem.
- O método `Reset` só irá zerar o contador, mas não irá começar a nova contagem.
- O `StartNew` realiza a mesma função do `Restart` mas retornando uma nova instância de um `Stopwatch`.

Documentação do [Stopwatch](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.startnew?view=netframework-4.8).